# Can you set up a SQL server maintenance plan to restore a database?

Tags: sql-server, maintenance

I am looking to setup a maintenance plan that makes a backup of a database (Database1) and then restores to another database (Database2) to confirm that it is able to restore successfully.

Can I do this as part of a maintenance plan and have SQL server mail me if it fails either the backup or the restore?

Comment: Do you need Database2 to exist afterwards? There's an option to verify the backup, which actually runs a restore (but doesn't leave a database behind)

Comment: The database isn't actually used by anything. I just need to confirm that the restore is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. After your backup task, add an Execute TSQL task that has the restore command. Join them together with a success constraint.

Add a Send Mail task and join it to both the backup task and the restore task. Make it an OR constraint and convert it to a failure constraint rather than success

Answer (score 0):

After update you have to fix orphaned users

with

EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'user', 'login', 'password'

for each user that access the database or you'll have errors in login from external applications.